# Debug Manim community in PyCharm

Tags: python, manim

Is there any way to debug a Manim **community** python script within PyCharm?

I found [this discussion](https://github.com/3b1b/manim/issues/981) for Manim 3b1b version but it doesn't apply to Manim community and I prefer to use the community version as it seems to be better documented.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Whenever I am debugging the library, I avoid using the CLI and render scenes directly from the file. Just add a snippet like this:

```
with tempconfig({"quality": "medium_quality"}):
    scene = YourSceneClass()
    scene.render()
```

And then the script can be run with the default Python debugger in PyCharm (at least that's how it is for me in VS Code).